# xlwings running problems about 'no module named win32api' in Windows

Tags: python, pycharm, xlwings

I got a problem of running 'xlwings' in Excel in Windows operating system. It gives me an error like this:

[image]

I have installed packages of "pywin32" and "comtype". I am confused why I still have this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Nothing posted after "this:", please make sure you include your code.

Comment: My code in Pycharm is: